# How to setup MVC routes to handle old ASP classic pages redirects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp-classic, routes

I'm migrating a ASP classic site to ASP.net MVC.
**Is there a way to redirect the old traffic to the new one?**

Example: how to go from:

```
www.mydomain.com/viewpage.asp?pageid=1234
```

to:

```
www.mydomain.com/page/1234
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Researching the issue I found that the best way was to:

1. Use a redirect engine (like [urlrewriter.net](http://urlrewriter.net/))
2. Redirect in the BeginRequest method

I ended up using #2 because it more simple for my project

```
Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  
   Dim fullOriginalpath As String = Request.Url.ToString.ToLower

   If (fullOriginalpath.Contains("/viewpage.asp?pageid=")) Then
      Context.Response.StatusCode = 301 'issue a permanent redirect'
      Context.Response.Redirect("/page/" + getPageIDFromPath(fullOriginalpath))
    End If

End Sub
```

You could use `Context.RewritePath` too, but it does not change the url in the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may have to use response.redirect in the 404 error page and map the query string input to the required new page. Round about way but works